# Export Excel sheet data to already existing database by adding new field

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a table which has data already with many fields. Now I want to add another field and for that field I want import data from Excel sheet. Is it possible to import data from Excel sheet to an already existing table or should I create a new table for importing data from Excel sheet?

Comment: do you want to `export or import`??

Comment: I want to import data

Comment: save as the excel file into `csv` and than you can directly import that csv to mysql.. and than write a custom php code to put that data into another table

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) - i's a library that lets you create new Excel files and read existing Excel files. It's very well documented, you shouldn't have any problems.

Once you've retrieved your data from the Excel file, use a simple [INSERT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) statement to insert these data in your database.

Good luck! :)